# Route file doesn't route to the right controller, once updated

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have this problem :

I have my route file, containing a valid route to a controller.
I compile, I have no error. I send a request, it calls the right method on the right controller, everything is working.

Then I changed the name of that controller and changed it in the route file.
I compile, I have no error. But when I send a request (I see it via my proxy), the request is never transmitted to the controller.

If I change the name of the controller back to the first one, it works !!

I have reboot and clean-all, but nothing works, do you have an idea ?

**Edit**

routes

```
## Créer le social user
POST    /v1/current_user     api.v1.controllers.CurrentUserController.create()
```

CurrentUserController

```
public class CurrentUserController extends Controller {
    @Transactional
    @CheckSecurity
    public static Result create() {
        return ok();
    }
}
```

Didn't mentionend it but I'm using play 2.1.1
@Transactional is because I use JPA instead of Ebean
@CheckSecurity calls a plugin I have written
But even if I didn't set this two annotations, it works when the name of the controller is UserController, but since I changed it to CurrentUserController, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add the routes file and the controllers?

Comment: Show us the declarations that doesn't work (controller and route) I had similar case with `Play 2.1.x` but cleaning the instance solved it.

Answer (score 1):

do a play clean and also clean all the class files, sometimes play is not good in cleaning after itself.

i would do a find . | grep classes and manually delete all the class folders

Comment: Thanks for your asnwer, I deleted all the files under target/,project/project and project/target ... still not working !